# Make PHP loop echo in reversed order

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, phpmyadmin

I'm making a simple webpage where anyone can type in a text in a textfiel, and that text will be stored to a database and placed on the screen. At the moment, the text that was posted most recently gets placed at the bottom at the page. I want it to be reversed; the newest at the top and the oldest at the bottom.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>JANNEchat Beta</title></head>
<form action="index.php" method="post" />
<p>Send a message to JANNES database: <input type="text" name="input1" />   
      </p><input type="submit" value"Submit" />
</form>

</html>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
define('DB_NAME', 'janne');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
die('Nu är något vajsing, kunde inte ansluta ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Nu spelas det trix, kan inte hitta databasen ' . DB_NAME . ' : ' .        
             mysql_error());   }

$value = isset($_POST['input1']) ? $_POST['input1'] : '';

if($value != ''){
$sql = "INSERT INTO janne (String) VALUES ('$value')";
if(!mysql_query($sql)){
die('vajsing: ' . mysql_error());
}
}

mysql_close();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "janne";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT String FROM janne";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$a = $result->num_rows - $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//THE PROBLEM IS HERE, I GUESS.     
    echo $row["String"] . "<br>";
   }
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: well done! But to make it sql-injection-safe please always use "$sql = "INSERT INTO janne (String) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."')";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update your `SQL`

```
$sql = "SELECT String FROM janne ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Here `id` may be the `Auto Increment` field in your table.

Comment: What do you mean with
"Here id may be the Auto Increment field in your table."?
what should i type instead of id?
My database is called janne, and the table is called janne, and the "column" name is called String.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have any other field in the table?

Comment: No, I don't. Should I?

Comment: Yes, you should have a primary key to identify the rows. Add one auto increment field.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, can you help me somehow? Maybe you can guide me if i show you this picture?
https://db.tt/oALc9DtX